# How does getItem() in an arrayAdapter work?

Tags: android, listview

I've read lots of tutorials from my manual and on the internet that explain the getView method, but I haven't understood why they use it.
Could anyone explain it to me with some examples or snippets?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`getItem()` returns the item's data object. It provides a way for you to access data in the adapter. For example, your array adapter holds string elements, `getItem()` returns a string object.

Answer (score 13):

getView() is used to construct or reuse the child item of your AdapterView.
AdapterView is a view that contains multiple items. For example, a ListView contains some items that have the same (or might not) structure. getView() is used to build the View at some position and fill it with data.

getItem() is used to get the item that provides a data for the specified View item.
For example, getItem() must return a String or CharSequence if you have a ListView of text items. This is made for convenience, for example in your onItemClickListener

```
@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> av, View view, int pos,
    long arg3) {

    String selectedText = (String) av.getItemAtPosition(pos);
    // or av.getAdapter().getItem(pos);
}
```