# How to get document id in In FirestorePagingAdapter?

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, android-paging

I am trying to use the `FirestorePagingAdapter` to display a list of all users in my firestore database. I am using `FirestorePagingAdapter` instead of FirestoreRecyclerAdapter to minimize the number of reads as F`irestorePagingAdapter`doesn't read the whole list of documents while `FirestoreRecyclerAdapter` does. I am able to display the paginated list successfully but I need to implement `onClickListener` onto it and on click of every item, I need to open another activity which shows a detailed description of the particular user which was clicked. For this, I need to pass the documentId of the clicked user to the next activity.

But unfortunately, ***FirestorePagingAdapter doesn't have getSnapshots() method so that I use getSnapshots().getSnapshot(position).getId().***

On the other hand, FirestoreRecyclerAdapter has this method which makes fetching the document id a very easy task. Something like this: [How to get document id or name in Android in Firestore db for passing on to another activity?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47986504/how-to-get-document-id-or-name-in-android-in-firestore-db-for-passing-on-to-anot/47995871#47995871)

```
// Query to fetch documents from user collection ordered by name
Query query = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance().collection("users")
                .orderBy("name");

// Setting the pagination configuration
PagedList.Config config = new PagedList.Config.Builder()
                .setEnablePlaceholders(false)
                .setPrefetchDistance(10)
                .setPageSize(20)
                .build();


FirestorePagingOptions<User> firestorePagingOptions = new FirestorePagingOptions.Builder<User>()
                .setLifecycleOwner(this)
                .setQuery(query, config, User.class)
                .build();

firestorePagingAdapter =
                new FirestorePagingAdapter<User, UserViewHolder>(firestorePagingOptions){

                    @NonNull
                    @Override
                    public UserViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
                        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                                .inflate(R.layout.single_user_layout, parent, false);

                        return new UserViewHolder(view);
                    }

                    @Override
                    protected void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull UserViewHolder holder, int position, @NonNull User user) {
                        holder.setUserName(user.name);
                        holder.setStatus(user.status);
                        holder.setThumbImage(user.thumb_image, UsersActivity.this);


                        holder.mView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(View v) {
                                Intent userProfileIntent = new Intent(UsersActivity.this, UserProfileActivity.class);
                                // Need to fetch the user_id to pass it as intent extra
                                // String user_id = getSnapshots().getSnapshot(position).getId();
                                // userProfileIntent.putExtra("user_id", user_id);
                                startActivity(userProfileIntent);
                            }
                        });
                    }
                };
```

Comment: Or you can skip using FirestorePagingAdapter and bind the results of a query to a RecyclerView yourself.  Recommended modern app architecture uses Android Jetpack with Firebase SDKs as shown in this repo.  https://github.com/CodingDoug/firebase-jetpack

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was able to do this by using `SnapshotParser` in `setQuery` method. Through this, I was able to modify the object which I got from the firestore. The `documentSnapshot.getId()` method returns the document id.

```
FirestorePagingOptions<User> firestorePagingOptions = new FirestorePagingOptions.Builder<User>()
                .setLifecycleOwner(this)
                .setQuery(query, config, new SnapshotParser<User>() {
                    @NonNull
                    @Override
                    public User parseSnapshot(@NonNull DocumentSnapshot snapshot) {
                        User user = snapshot.toObject(User.class);
                        user.userId = snapshot.getId();
                        return user;
                    }
                })
                .build();
```

In the User class, I just added another field "String userId" in the User class. The userId field doesn't exist in my firestore document.
In the `onClickListener`, I can then directly use `user.userId` to get the document id and send it to other activity.

Comment: Still work? I need get update documents but i'm using the FirestorePagingAdapter now

Answer (score 1):

While trying to access the document snapshot from itemView, I found out [this](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Adapter#getItem(int))

```
itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                int pos = getAdapterPosition();
                if (pos != RecyclerView.NO_POSITION && listener != null) {
                    String docId = getItem(pos).getId();
                    Toast.makeText(context, "doc Id: "+docId, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    //listener.onItemClick(getSnapshots().getSnapshot(pos), pos, docId);
                    listener.onItemClick(getItem(pos), pos, docId); 
                }
            }
        });
```

As mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14030555/4648976), the `getItem()` returns the item's data object.

Answer (score 0):

As you already noticed:

```
String id = getSnapshots().getSnapshot(position).getId();
```

Doesn't work, it works only when using `FirestoreRecyclerAdapter`. So to solve this, you need to store the id of the document as property of your document. If the id of the document is the id of the user that comes from the Firebase autentication, then simply store that `uid`. If you are not using the `uid`, get the id of the document and pass it to the `User` constructor when creating a new object like this:

```
FirebaseFirestore rootRef = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
CollectionReference usersRef = rootRef.collection("users");
String id = eventsRef.document().getId();
User user = new User(id, name, status, thumb_image);
usersRef.document(id).set(user);
```

Comment: Is this a right approach or should create my own adapter extending the `FirestoreRecyclerAdapter` and then use the query cursors to paginate the data
(https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/query-cursors).

Comment: Yes it is the right approach. There is no need in this case to create a custom adapter as you can simply pass the id of the user to the constructor and use then `user.id` in your `onClick()` method.

Comment: Alex, please see [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56064579/6134137). I was able to find a middle way that neither involve storing the uid in the document nor using the custom adapter.

Comment: It's a good solution but it solves the problem only locally. Why do I say that? If you'll find yourself later in the project in the position in which you need to remove a user from the database based on his id, please note that you cannot do it. This is because you cannot perform such a query since the user id does not exist in the database, right?

Comment: @AlexMamo When using getSnapshots().getSnapshot(position).getId(), does this count as an additional document read? Thanks

Comment: @user1823280 It counts as the initial document read, it's not an additional document read.

Comment: By initial document read, you mean the read occurred while binding the retrieved document to the RecyclerView, right?

Comment: I just found out that `String docId = getItem(pos).getId();` will work.

Answer (score 0):

I spent a day trying to get the id of the document as I am now using the FirestorePagingAdapter. For Kotlin this is what worked for me

```
override fun onBindViewHolder(viewHolder: LyricViewHolder, position: Int, song: Lyric) {
                // Bind to ViewHolder
                viewHolder.bind(song)

                viewHolder.itemView.setOnClickListener { view ->

                    val id = getItem(position)?.id

                    var bundle = bundleOf("id" to id)
                    view.findNavController().navigate(R.id.songDetailFragment, bundle)
                }
            }
```

Hope this helps someone else in the near future. Can post full code and fully explain if anyone is confused. Happy coding!

Answer (score -1):

Try using this

```
getSnapshots().getSnapshot(position).getId()
```

Comment: Quote from the question "But unfortunately, FirestorePagingAdapter doesn't have getSnapshots() method so that I use getSnapshots().getSnapshot(position).getId()."